# meaning of "to get their hands on one of their hand"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Can anyone tell me please what this sentence means?

"As the doors opened for the launch of the gadget, swarm of people rushed inside to get their hands on one of their hand."

Thank you.

Comment: Where did this sentence come from?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense.  First, it should be either "a swarm of people" or "swarms of people".  Similarly, it should be "one of their hands" and not "one of their hand".  (Because "one of" requires a group of things, one of which is being referenced.)  But more importantly, to "get one's hands" on something means to acquire it, grasp it, find it; you might say "He finally got his hands on a copy of the book", or "She couldn't wait to get her hands on the violin."